# Weird result from applying power rule of logarithm

Tags: exponentiation

I was working on a integration problem involving $3^u$ and noticed something weird.

If you assign the value $x = e^3$ then you have that $3^u = ln x^u$. This is also equal to $ulnx$.

Heres the weird part $ulnx = u lne^3 = 3u$. I cant find any explanation for this and can't find a way t prove its wrong other than my common sense. Please can anyone help me.

Comment: How did you get from $x = e^3$ to $3^u = \ln x^u$?  What is $u$ there?

Comment: If $x = e^3$, than $3^u = (\ln(x))^u$ which is NOT the same as $u\ln(x)$

Comment: Here is your problem.  $(\ln x)^u \ne \ln (x^u)$

Comment: Oh ok, I don't know why i didn't see that. Pretty stupid of me. Thanks anyways